# one eclipse install not displaying utf8

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, utf-8

I have Eclipse installed on an old machine and a new machine. I download from svn repository on old Eclipse, UTF8 character in a java file displays fine. I download onto new Eclipse, UTF8 character displays as "?". I deduce that the file is saved correctly in SVN. I have checked some settings in Preferences>... between the two Eclipse installs and they appear the same.  Which preferences should I investigate? Remember, I have at least one eclipse on one machine working as expected.

Comment: Are both using the same font for that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workspace-wide encoding is configured here (*Windows* -> *Preferences* -> *General* -> *Workspace*):

[image: Workspace-wide encoding options]

If it is not working as expected, the project probably overrides the settings (*Right click on project* -> *Properties* -> *Resources*):

[image: Project encoding options]